# why my first spark/yarn app doesn't start (spark-submit error)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am newbie in distributed system, big data. I recently started with Hadoop/yarn and spark(spark on yarn platform) for my graduation project and for now, I am blocked in.
I want to start my first spark application but I don't know the issue. when I use spark-submit to start the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from pyspark import SparkContext 

sc=SparkContext("local[*]",appName="app") 
data = sc.textFile("test.txt") 
print(data.collect()) 

from numpy import array 
parsedData = data.map(lambda line:array([float(x) for x in line.split(' ')])) 
print(parsedData.collect())
```

this error shows up( unable to load Hadoop library...) 
if someone can help me, please.

Here's a capture of the error:
[image: a capture here for the error]

Comment: what is in your python file?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python from pyspark import SparkContext sc=SparkContext("local[*]",appName="app") data = sc.textFile("test.txt") print(data.collect()) from numpy import array parsedData = data.map(lambda line:array([float(x) for x in line.split(' ')])) print(parsedData.collect())

Comment: is your file located at the correct path? check the path for python file or use the absolute path.

Comment: yes it is, same problem trying with the full path.

Comment: The warning can be ignored. Issue is definitely with placement of your .py file. You are also using a risky approach in `sc.textFile("test.txt")` Use absolute paths for both local and HDFS files to avoid such unnecessary pains